# to_sql doesn't work when pluck is involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I to `to_sql` on the following query it works fine:

```
2.1.8 :017 > Task.joins(:recurrence).group('recurrences.id').to_sql
 => "SELECT `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` INNER JOIN `recurrences` ON `recurrences`.`id` = `tasks`.`recurrence_id` GROUP BY recurrences.id"
```

But then when I add `pluck` it doesn't work:

```
2.1.8 :018 > Task.joins(:recurrence).group('recurrences.id').pluck('tasks.title').to_sql
   (21.0ms)  SELECT tasks.title FROM `tasks` INNER JOIN `recurrences` ON `recurrences`.`id` = `tasks`.`recurrence_id` GROUP BY recurrences.id
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sql' for #<Array:0x007fbde9863f18>
```

Apparently the addition of `pluck` changes the type of object from `ActiveRecord_Relation` to `Array`, and you obviously can't perform `to_sql` on an array.

What I'm wanting it to output (for starters) is this:

```
SELECT tasks.title FROM `tasks` INNER JOIN `recurrences` ON `recurrences`.`id` = `tasks`.`recurrence_id` GROUP BY recurrences.id
```

...which is in fact what I copy/pasted from the query generated by `Task.joins(:recurrence).group('recurrences.id').pluck('tasks.title')` without the `to_sql`.

Is it possible to do what I'm wanting to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I have to use `select`.

```
> Task.select('tasks.title').joins(:recurrence).group('recurrences.id').to_sql
 => "SELECT tasks.title FROM `tasks` INNER JOIN `recurrences` ON `recurrences`.`id` = `tasks`.`recurrence_id` GROUP BY recurrences.id"
```

Comment: Worths mention that is because `pluck` is an eager method (as `find`), it goes immediately to database and return array of results. Docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) and [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck)