# Why doesn't to_sql work on all ActiveRecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The very handy `.to_sql` doesn't work on some queries, for example this works

```rb
User.all.to_sql
```

but this doesn't

```rb
User.find(1).to_sql
```

I noticed a comment here that [.pluck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798527/to-sql-doesnt-work-when-pluck-is-involved#comment78737251_39798605) also doesn't work, but I don't understand why. This is for my own understanding rather than to solve a practical problem, I hope that's okay.

Comment: `User.find(1)` does not return an ActiveRecord query, that's why.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks Sergio, can you explain why, I thought it would generate something like SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1. Is it doing that and just not doing it through AR, or is it not doing that at all? I think to_sql may do something more nuanced than I expected, but I just can't figure out where the line is between what it will convert to sql and what it won't.

Comment: Yes, it is doing exactly that AND it executes this query immediately, returning you one `User`. Whereas `User.all` returns a query/relation, which is not executed (sent to the DB) until you try to enumerate the results (with `each`, `to_a` or otherwise)

Comment: " it is doing exactly that" - correction, it is doing `select * from users where id = 1 limit 1`

Comment: If you wanted to see that query then it would have to be changed to `User.where(id: 1).limit(1).to_sql`